# submitHandler: function(form) not working

Tags: jquery

I am not recieving error while submitting form and it does validation but error should be displayed. as i see database entry is not happening on submit as in empty fields.

What could be issue?
Html code span-> displaying code here.

```
 <div class="addinput mt-2 form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subcategory[]" id="name" class="inputname" style="width: 251px;margin-left: 64px;">
                 <span>

                 </span>       
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnAddSubCategory" style="margin: 20px;">Add Sub
                    Category</button>
            </div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submitClass").on("click", function(){
        $("#myForm").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                alert("Submitted!");
                var error = errorHandler(); // function call
                if (error == 0) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        })
    });

    function errorHandler() { //function define
        error = 0; //Error set = 0; Always...    
        $(".inputname").each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) { // 'visible' function takes the hideen field or stlye="display:none"
                if ($(this).val() == '') // if value/ field is empty    
                {
                    $(this).next('span').html("Please Enter Category Name").css("color", "red"); // message given on NEXT DIV TAG using html function html("yourmessage");
                    error++;
                }
            }
        })            
        return error;
    }
```

Comment: are u getting any error in console? form.submit() should be $("#myForm").submit();

Comment: @Nero There is no error in console.